# Клиент-Серверное приложение. Прошу помочь с учебным заданием по UDP протоколу

Tags: c, клиент-сервер, передача-данных

Программа-клиент отправляет на сервер текстовое сообщение размером в 8 символов(для удобства и проверки), но при этом нужно, чтобы программа принудительно пропускала несколько пакетов. Это нужно для того чтобы в программе Сервер была функция перезапроса недошедших пакетов. 
Прошу объяснить как реализовать принудительный пропуск пакетов и функцию перезапроса.
Можно все сделать проще с помощью ТСР, но задание требует использовать именно UDP.

Клиент

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
char buff[10 *1014];
printf("UDP DEMO Client\nType quit to quit\n");

// Шаг 1 - иницилизация библиотеки Winsocks
if (WSAStartup(0x202, (WSADATA*)& buff[0]))
{
    printf("WSAStartup error: %d\n",
        WSAGetLastError());
    return -1;
}

// Шаг 2 - открытие сокета
SOCKET my_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (my_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("socket() error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

// Шаг 3 - обмен сообщений с сервером
HOSTENT* hst;
sockaddr_in dest_addr;

dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// определение IP-адреса узла
if (inet_addr(SERVERADDR))
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERADDR);
else
    if (hst = gethostbyname(SERVERADDR))
        dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((unsigned long**)
            hst->h_addr_list)[0][0];
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown host: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(my_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

while (1)
{
    char buff1[9];
    // чтение сообщения с клавиатуры
    printf("S<=C:"); 
    fgets(&buff[0], sizeof(buff1), stdin);
    if (!strcmp(&buff[0], "quit\n")) 
        break;

    // Передача сообщений на сервер
    sendto(my_sock, &buff[0], strlen(&buff[0]), 0,
        (sockaddr*)& dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));

    // Прием сообщения с сервера
    sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int server_addr_size = sizeof(server_addr);

    int n = recvfrom(my_sock, &buff[0], sizeof(buff) - 1, 0,
        (sockaddr*)& server_addr, &server_addr_size);

    if (n == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recvfrom() error:"\
            "%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(my_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    buff[n] = 0;

    // Вывод принятого с сервера сообщения на экран
    printf("S=>C:%s \n", &buff[0]);
}
```

Сервер

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
char buff[400];

printf("UDP DEMO echo-Server\n");

// шаг 1 - подключение библиотеки 
if (WSAStartup(0x202, (WSADATA*)& buff[0]))
{
    printf("WSAStartup error: %d\n",
        WSAGetLastError());
    return -1;
}

// шаг 2 - создание сокета
SOCKET my_sock;
my_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (my_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Socket() error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

// шаг 3 - связывание сокета с локальным адресом 
sockaddr_in local_addr;
local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (bind(my_sock, (sockaddr*)& local_addr,
    sizeof(local_addr)))
{
    printf("bind error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(my_sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

// шаг 4 обработка пакетов, присланных клиентами
while (1)
{
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    int bsize = recvfrom(my_sock, &buff[0],
        sizeof(buff) - 1, 0,
        (sockaddr*)& client_addr, &client_addr_size);
    if (bsize == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("recvfrom() error: %d\n",
            WSAGetLastError());

    // Определяем IP-адрес клиента и прочие атрибуты
    HOSTENT* hst;
    hst = gethostbyaddr((char*)
        & client_addr.sin_addr, 4, AF_INET);
    printf("+%s [%s:%d] new DATAGRAM!\n",
        (hst) ? hst->h_name : "Unknown host",
        inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
        ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

    // добавление завершающего нуля
    buff[bsize] = 0;

    // Вывод на экран 
    printf("C=>S:%s\n", &buff[0]);
    Sleep(2000);

    // посылка датаграммы клиенту
    const char Answer[256] = "Complite\n";
    sendto(my_sock, Answer, sizeof (Answer), 0,
        (sockaddr*)& client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));
}
```

[image: Отправка данных]

[image: Сервер]

Comment: Эти 8 символов в скорее всего один пакет попадут. Пакеты, вроде как, по 1-1.5 Кбайт идут.

Comment: @Bogdan Это вы с TCP перепутали

Comment: @Bogdan Если так, то как я могу создать, например несколько пакетов? Буду рад если объясните или дадите ссылку.

Comment: суть задания непонятна. вы не можете контролировать транспортный уровень протокола удп и заставить его "пропустить" пару датаграмм, в свою очередь ТСР гарантирует доставку и сам заправшивает пакет повторно, если тот не дошел

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема пропустить несколько пакетов? Заводите счетчик пропускаемых пакетов и при получении пакета смотрите, нулевой этот счетчик или нет, если нулевой - то обрабатываете пакет, если нет - то игнорируете пакет и уменьшаете счетчик на 1.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо, глянул в википедии, максимальный размер 65535 байт. Тем не менее, 8 отладочных байт скорее всего пойдут одной датаграммой.

Comment: @Bogdan, гадать не надо. Надо смотреть любым анализатором пакетов.

Comment: @Bogdan При отправке по UDP каждая порция данных всегда отправляется одной датаграммой, тут нет никаких "скорее всего".

Comment: @VTT Добавил скрины. На сервере это же 2 пакета(дейтаграммы)?

Comment: Во-первых у вас на клиенте при вызове `fgets` буфер и размер буфера не соответствуют. И непонятно, с чего это отправляется сразу 16 байт, когда размер буфера указан до 9

Comment: @VTT я только начал изучать все это и мало что понимаю, но если я укажу одинаковый размер буфера в 'fgets', то выдает ошибку и данные в сервер не отправляются

Comment: Вместе с пакетом отправляйте его порядковый номер. Скажем, один байт (первый) является номером пакета, оставшиеся 7 байт - полезной нагрузкой. В клиенте каждое третье сообщение от пользователя не отправляйте. Сервер в ответ пусть шлёт пакет подверждение о получении пакета от клиента с номером таким-то. И когда нужен перезапрос - сервер пошлёт клиенту пакет с номером пакета для перезапроса. Вы его у себя найдете и отправите заново.

Comment: @vegorov то что на скриншоте, я же правильно понимаю, сообщение длиной 16 символов разделилось на 2 пакета по 8 символов, а не просто 1 пакет?

Comment: То что на скриншоте - никак не связано с тем, что у Вас в исходниках. Ну в смысле у Вас `fgets(&buff[9], sizeof(buff1), stdin);` - Вы пишите в массив `buff` начиная с элемента с индексом 9 до 9 символов из стандартного ввода. Потом Вы сравниваете строку, начинающуюся в buff[0] с строкой "quit", потом вы отправляете строку, начинающуюся в buff[0] на сервер. Это не должно работать. Скриншоты откуда ?

Comment: А ещё Вы пишите в условии про учебное задание, но директорию называете Тестовое задание. Странно это всё.

Comment: @vegorov прошу прощения, я играл со значениями буфера, после советов выше, а потом правил код здесь, исправил. Тестовое задание для прохода более сильную подгруппу в универе :) А попасть туда очень хочется

Comment: Вы ввели 16 символов, а читаете из stdin по `9-1` + плюс завершающий ноль (`'\0'`) символов. Вот и получается две итерации (первые 8 символов, вторые 8 символов) на отправку. Заведите счётчик итераций, и если он делится на 3 - игнорируйте, то есть не вызывайте пару sendto/recvfrom в клиенте. Таким образом вы будете "пропускать" каждый третий пакет. Во всех остальных случаях читайте ответ от сервера, ответ должен быть либо подверждение что пакет доставлен, либо запрос на переотправку пакета с номером таким-то. Ключевой момент - нумеруйте пакеты. Прям весь порядок дейтсвий мне лень придумывать

Comment: Можно завести очередь пакетов на отправку (на клиенте). И пока не пришло подверждение от сервера, что пакет с номером таким-то обработан сервером - пакет из очереди не удалять. Тогда при получении подверждения от сервера вы будете удалять пакет из очереди,а и брать следующий, а при получении запроса на переотправку вместо подтверждения, искать этот пакет в очереди и отправлять заново.